# Bigcommerce | Stencil - Why is the recommended node version for windows so old?

Tags: bigcommerce

The [Stencil pre-requisites page](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/prerequisites) recommends only installing LTS versions of node, and the specifically recommends Node 4.4.0 for the Mac and 4.1.2 for Linux.

However for Windows the recommended version is 0.12.7 even though the current LTS is 4.4.5. Is there a particular issue on Windows with newer versions or is the documentation just outdated?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the latest BigCommerce-tested versions on each operating system. You can try the current LTS, but issues may arise.